# How did the altar indicate that the sons of Shaul were to be killed?

Tags: capital-punishment, maseches-sanhedrin, king-david, king-saul, mizbeach-altar

In [Yerushalmi Sanhedrin 6:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Sanhedrin.29b.1?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi) (also found in [bYevamot 79a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.79a.4?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) with an alternate *girsa*) King David uses the altar to indicate which of Shaul's son's should be given over to the Gibeonim.

> אמר להן הריני מעבירן לפני המזבח כל שהמזבח קולטו הרי הוא שלו מפני מפיבושת שהיה גדול בתורה לפני המזבח וקלטו.

My question is the meaning of the phrase "מזבח קולטו" was this something miraculous? How exactly did the altar indicate which person should be given over and which should be spared?

Comment: If the Aron held them back they were given over if not they were spared.How  can that not be understood as  something miraculous?

Comment: @Schmerel 1. It appears the correct girsa is the altar 2. there is a principle that one who grabs the horns of the altar may not be removed to be killed

Comment: As the Gemara   Yevamot 79A says,  according  to the Torah  they never should have  been killed  to  begin with.  This  was  a  special situation  where they had to.

Comment: Yehoshua used a similar process to find who took from the city of עי.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Rabbi Steinsaltz's commentary](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.79a.4?lang=bi&p2=Steinsaltz_on_Yevamot.79a.4&lang2=bi) on the version in the Bavli, they were all passed near the Ark, brushing against it and whoever had to die stayed glue to the Ark and couldn't move. Therefore, we may say that according to the Yerushalmi (this version, by the way, also appears in [Bamidbar Rabbah 8:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bamidbar_Rabbah.8.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and in [Yerushalmi Kiddushin 42b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Kiddushin.42b.1?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)), the people who had to die became glued to the altar upon brushing against it.